# Как прочитать все элементы списка с другого приложения с помощью SendMessage?

Tags: c++, winapi, keydown, sendmessage

Совсем недавно начал разбираться с WinApi. Есть список примерно такого вида:
[image: список элементов]

Посылая сообщение вида:

```
SendMessageW(ListHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, NULL);
```

Фокус ожидаемо переходит на вторую строку. В случае с проводником такое сообщение тоже проходит. А как быть с такими списками (для примера контактный список скайпа):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посылая VK_DOWN + VK_RETURN ничего не происходит. Как в данном случае пройти весь список, чтобы каждый элемент находился в фокусе?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть, какие события отправляются окну через утилиту [spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242713(v=vs.60).aspx), когда вы например, переходите вниз-вверх стрелками и наживаете Enter.

Comment: А вручную `вниз` с последующим `enter` работает должным образом на списке скайпа?

Comment: @alexolut Да, в ручную всё работает прекрасно.

Comment: @Flowneee Spy++ не отслеживает сообщения(именно в случае со скайпом)